# Python : string split with either A or B

Tags: python, regex

I have :

```
 s='"Tag":"Football","name":"Mickael A","Played":"10times","Tag":"Basket","name":"Bruce B","Played":"8times","Tag":"Football","name":"John R","Played":"6times",'
```

I want to split based on Football and Basket ie to have :

```
['','"Mickael A","Played":"10times"',
'"Bruce B","Played":"8times",',
'"John R","Played":"6times",']
```

I tried :

```
s.strip().split(r'"Tag":("Football"|"Basket"),"name":')
```

But it is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what you need is to use the `re` library and to make the Football and Basketball non capturing groups so they don't appear in the result like so :

```
import re
re.split(r'"Tag":(?:"Football"|"Basket"),"name":', s)
```

the result would be :

```
['', '"Mickael A","Played":"10times",', '"Bruce B","Played":"8times",', '"John R","Played":"6times",']
```

Answer (score 2):

Analyzing your string, it seems you need:

```
re.findall(r'"name":(.*?),(?:"Tag"|$)', s)
```

where, `s` is your string. This finds all occurances of something (`.*?`) followed by `"name":` and preceded by `,"Tag"` or `,<end>`

**Full code**:

```
import re

s = '"Tag":"Football","name":"Mickael A","Played":"10times","Tag":"Basket","name":"Bruce B","Played":"8times","Tag":"Football","name":"John R","Played":"6times",'

print(re.findall(r'"name":(.*?),(?:"Tag"|$)', s))
# ['"Mickael A","Played":"10times"', '"Bruce B","Played":"8times"', '"John R","Played":"6times"']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following Regex with `re.split`:

```
"Tag":"[^"]+","name":
```

- `"Tag":"` matches literally
- `[^"]+` matches one or more characters that are not `"` i.e. matches upto next `"`
- `","name":` matches literally

You can use non-greedy pattern `.*?"` instead of `[^"]+` as well:

```
"Tag":".*?","name":'
```

**Example:**

```
In [486]: s = '"Tag":"Football","name":"Mickael A","Played":"10times","Tag":"Basket","name":"Bruce B","Played":"8times","Tag":"Football","name":"John R","Played":"6times",'

In [487]: re.split(r'"Tag":"[^"]+","name":', s)
Out[487]: 
['',
 '"Mickael A","Played":"10times",',
 '"Bruce B","Played":"8times",',
 '"John R","Played":"6times",']

In [488]: re.split(r'"Tag":".*?","name":', s)
Out[488]: 
['',
 '"Mickael A","Played":"10times",',
 '"Bruce B","Played":"8times",',
 '"John R","Played":"6times",']
```

Answer (score 0):

`re` library does what you need.

```
import re

s='"Tag":"Football","name":"Mickael A","Played":"10times","Tag":"Basket","name":"Bruce B","Played":"8times","Tag":"Football","name":"John R","Played":"6times",'
re.split('Football|Basket', s)
```

it returns

```
>>> ['"Tag":"',
     '","name":"Mickael A","Played":"10times","Tag":"',
     '","name":"Bruce B","Played":"8times","Tag":"',
     '","name":"John R","Played":"6times",']
```

Answer (score 0):

the better approach will be structuring this string and I am assuming name played and game (which is repeated is related to one person). after this list of dict you can easily manipulate the data

```
s='"Tag":"Football","name":"Mickael A","Played":"10times","Tag":"Basket","name":"Bruce B","Played":"8times","Tag":"Football","name":"John R","Played":"6times",'


l=[]
def fun(s):
 return str('{')+s+str('}')
import ast


k = s.strip().split(',')

for i in range(0,len(k),3):
    dic={}
    if len(k[i].split(':'))==2:
        dic['Tag']=ast.literal_eval(fun(k[i]))['Tag']
        dic['name']=ast.literal_eval(fun(k[i+1]))['name']
        dic['Played']=ast.literal_eval(fun(k[i+2]))['Played']
        l.append(dic)
print(l)
'''
output

[{'Tag': 'Football', 'name': 'Mickael A', 'Played': '10times'}, {'Tag': 'Basket', 'name': 'Bruce B', 'Played': '8times'}, {'Tag': 'Football', 'name': 'John R', 'Played': '6times'}]

'''
```